# CSS Keyframe animation on an image in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, css-animations

I' trying to implement [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MMNEEdGa5eE) straight-forward keyframe animation. But nothing moves.

The Waves component is in its own file, and the component is called from of a Grid component. Could this cause the trouble?

```
-src/App.js <-- Grid.js called here
-src/animations/Waves.js
-src/components/Grid.js <-- Waves.js called here
-public/index.css
```

React component looks like this:

```
const Waves = () => {
  return (
    <section>
      <div className='singleWave waveAnimation'>
        <Image src={wave}></Image>
      </div>
    </section>
  )
}
```

css-file here:

```
.singleWave {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: url("../src/pics/wave.png"); 
  background-size: "1000px, 100px";
  top: 0.7vh;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.waveAnimation {
  animation: "animate   30s linear infinite";
  z-index: 1000;
  opacity: 0.8;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  bottom: 0;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    background-position-x: 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position-x: 1000px;
  }
}

@keyframes animate2
{   

  0% {
    background-position-x: 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position-x: -1000px;
  }
}
```

Sure, its unnecessary to declare the image twice (imported in the component and in the css-file). But the animation seems to work with neither of the two.

Comment: Where is your animate css function?

Comment: Oops, you're right. It was there, didn't put it above. Added it there now.

Comment: You want to animate div background image? Or img inside div?

Comment: Image inside div

Comment: you need to animate your image instead of parent div

Comment: That makes sense. After all, I ended up using styled-components and styled.divs.